# number of generators of a semi direct product

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

Let $G$ be a finite group. Let $g(G)$ be the minimum set of elements of $G$ required to generate the whole group.

Suppose that $G= H \rtimes K$ is a semi direct product of two finitely generated groups $H$ and $K$. I want to know if there are relations between $g(G)$ and $g(H), g(K)$.

More specifically let $\{(h_i,k_j)\}_{(i,j)\in I \times J}$ be a set of generators of the group $H \rtimes K$. There is a relation between $|I|$ with $g(H)$ and also between $|J|$, with $g(K)$?.

Comment: We have $g(G) \le g(H) + g(K)$. I don't know if one can say more than this in general.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan I'm interested in generator sets for the group $\mathbb{Z}_2^n \rtimes S_n$. Some conditions on the tuples $(h_i,k_i)$ or anything

Comment: That group is a Coxeter group called the hyperoctahedral group. It has a presentation by $n$ involutions which I believe is its Coxeter presentation: $(n-1)$ transpositions generating $S_n$, and the element $(-1, 1, 1, ...)$ in $\mathbb{Z}_2^n$. Here the nice thing that happens is that $S_n$ acts transitively on an obvious set of generators of $\mathbb{Z}_2^n$.

Comment: Ok, I'm asking because I'm considering actions of that family of groups on Riemann surfaces. There are some relations that involve the signature of an action and also a generating vector for the group. I'm trying to deduce some properties that the generating sets of this kind of group has.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generically you cannot show anything better than $g(K)\le g(H\rtimes K)\le g(H)+g(K)$ as both bounds are attained in examples.

Comment: What about the group $\mathbb{Z}_2 ^n \rtimes S_n$? Is there a way to find if it's possible to generate this group with only two generators when $n=3$?

Comment: It can be generated (actually in 9 different ways). If we write the group as $\langle (1,2),(1,3,5)(2,4,6), (1,3)(2,4)\rangle$, for example $(1,3)(2,4), (3,5,4,6) $ would be a generating pair. I suspect this holds for arbitrary $n$, but I've not tried to prove it.

Comment: I'm asking for generators for $\mathbb{Z}_2^3 \rtimes S_3$

Comment: These are generators for $Z_2^3\rtimes S_3$, considering the group as $C_2\wr S_3$.